# How to get all fingerprints for .ssh/authorized_keys(2) file

Tags: ssh, bash, ssh-keys, awk, ssh-keygen

Is there a simple way to get a list of all fingerprints entered in the .ssh/authorized_keys || .ssh/authorized_keys2 file?

```
ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/authorized_keys
```

will only return fingerprint of first line / entry / publickey

hack with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { 
    while (getline < ".ssh/authorized_keys") {
        if ($1!~"ssh-(r|d)sa") {continue}
        print "Fingerprint for "$3
        system("echo " "\""$0"\"> /tmp/authorizedPublicKey.scan; \
            ssh-keygen -l -f /tmp/authorizedPublicKey.scan; \
            rm /tmp/authorizedPublicKey.scan"
        )
    }
}'
```

but is there an easier way or ssh command I didn't find?

Comment: To do this reliably you have to consider the options field in the `authorized_keys` file, which the `ssh-keygen` baulks at. I looked for [a reliable way to parse it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343695) but the best I could come up with is covered by [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343713).

Comment: Please consider updating this question. Your command, `ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/authorized_keys`, now seems to fingerprint *all* keys in the file, at least with my version (OpenSSH_8.4p1). No need for hacky oneliners anymore!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Here's another hack using plain bash without temporary files:

```
while read l; do
  [[ -n $l && ${l###} = $l ]] && ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin <<<$l;
done < .ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can easily make it a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
function fingerprints() {
  local file="${1:-$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys}"
  while read l; do
    [[ -n $l && ${l###} = $l ]] && ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin <<<$l
  done < "${file}"
}
```

and call it with:

```
$ fingerprints .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: nice @Raphink , thank you.
added http://code.childno.de/marcel/changeset/afdce0dd ;)

One note: `ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin` seems not to work on a mac.. nevertheless not relevant for servers but *gnaa* apple or is it a BSD "problem" getting `/dev/stdin is not a public key file.`?!

Comment: Reading from `/dev/stdin` is not a great idea in general, it's better to use `-`, but for some reason `ssh-keygen` doesn't know about `-`...

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac?

Comment: This does not work if the keys are prefixed with options.

Comment: @ℝaphink: I'd go for `local file="${1:-$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys}"` to allow for it to work without any arguments and default to the usual `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and quote the `< "$file"` used as input to the `while` loop.

Comment: does not work with zsh

Comment: this works for me with prefixed options: `grep -o 'ssh-.*' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | xargs -n1 -I% sh -c 'echo "%" | ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin'`

Answer (score 11):

A one-liner based on the */dev/stdin* trick from [ℝaphink's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/413247/74509) and *[man xargs → EXAMPLES](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html#EXAMPLES)*:

```
egrep '^[^#]' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | xargs -n1 -I% bash -c 'ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin <<<"%"'
```

Comment: This works great, and given it's a one-liner, can easily be used to run the command via SSH. Thanks!

Comment: does not work with options field present in authorized_keys

Comment: this works for me: `grep -o 'ssh-.*' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | xargs -n1 -I% sh -c 'echo "%" | ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin'`

Answer (score 8):

Here's a portable way to show all key fingerprints for a given file, tested on Mac and Linux:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

fingerprint_keys()
{
    if (( $# != 1 )); then
        echo "Usage: ${FUNCNAME} <authorized keys file>" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    local file="$1"
    if [ ! -r "$file" ]; then
        echo "${FUNCNAME}: File '${file}' does not exist or isn't readable." >&2
        return 1
    fi

    # Must be declared /before/ assignment, because of bash weirdness, in
    # order to get exit code in $?.
    local TMPFILE

    TEMPFILE=$(mktemp -q -t "$0.XXXXXXXXXX")
    if (( $? != 0 )); then
        echo "${FUNCNAME}: Can't create temporary file." >&2
        return 1
    fi

    while read line; do
        # Make sure lone isn't a comment or blank.
        if [[ -n "$line" ]] && [ "${line###}" == "$line" ]; then
            # Insert key into temporary file (ignoring noclobber).
            echo "$line" >| "$TEMPFILE"

            # Fingerprint time.
            ssh-keygen -l -f "$TEMPFILE"

            # OVerwrite the file ASAP (ignoring noclobber) to not leave keys
            # sitting in temp files.
            >| "$TEMPFILE"
        fi
    done < "$file"

    rm -f "$TEMPFILE"
    if (( $? != 0 )); then
        echo "${FUNCNAME}: Failed to remove temporary file." >&2
        return 1
    fi
}
```

Example Usage:

```bsh
bash $ fingerprint_keys ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:bb:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  x@x.local (RSA)
bash $
```

Comment: sorry to say that but that's neither "simplier", nor "smaller" not even "smarter" and doesn't take another approach than listed above. just a script using more error handlers ;)

Comment: Which makes it safer, right? You're welcome to make edits but why downvote? I didn't propose that it was any kind of better solution than yours... I feel a secure tempfile is better, and that more safety is needed for scripting purposes. Also, the version above is noclobber-safe.

Comment: For a FreeBSD system (which does not use bash by default), I made the following changes:
Assuming bash is installed from ports, change the first line to `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`.  I then called the function by adding this as the last line: `fingerprint_keys $@`.  I saved the script as `fingerprints.bash`, marking it executable with `chmod u+x ./fingerprints.bash`.  Additionally, I added a comment to the file with the link to this answer, like so, near the top `# solution from "Will" on SO http://serverfault.com/a/615892/126742`.  Call it like so `./fingerprints.bash ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: @derekv: the more portable method is to use the following hashbang: `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, because the path for `env` is very portable and it tells `env` to execute the Bash it knows about.

Comment: The temporary file and all the machinations around it seem useless here; like most modern commands, `ssh-keygen -l -f -` reads from standard input just fine. Perhaps there was a time when it didn't, but then Bash provides `/dev/stdin` for those cases.

Answer (score 5):

Since recent versions of OpenSSH, this command already produces a nice listing for you:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f authorized_keys
```

Example:

```
# ssh-keygen -l -f authorized_keys
2048 SHA256:GzZ7.................................RqTEag foo (RSA)
2048 SHA256:/y0.......................................4 bar (RSA)
2048 SHA256:p.........................................k bleech (RSA)
```

So consider just upgrading your OpenSSH client.

Comment: that is already shown in the hoghest count answer? did you not read it?

Comment: Its a little different @djdomi in that is using stdin (the `-`) arg, which I was able to use like this `cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | ssh-keygen -lf -`.

Comment: It seems that there's no need to do something different anymore though. While the OP says that command will fingerprint the first key in the file only, I've just run it now and got fingerprints for all of them:

`wilmer@fiona:~$ ssh-keygen -l -f .ssh/authorized_keys`
`2048 SHA256:DEtyZ1E+22Gsx9g/k8Wdz2vMk3JyJ9ZgCxytb4aMYSc yubikey-ws-wilmer (RSA)`
`2048 SHA256:oIePQpcOShOhFlCIXZZv6wUCp96iX7Pg8cdFtTSb8Co yubikey-lap-wilmer (RSA)`
.....

Comment: It seems to me this should be the accepted answer nowadays

Answer (score 1):

And should anyone need to do it on Windows / in PowerShell:

```
gc authorized_keys | foreach {$_ |ssh-keygen -l -f -}
```

or the fully-blown version without aliases looking for your user profile directory:

```
(Get-Content ((Get-Content env:/userprofile)+"/.ssh/authorized_keys")) | foreach {$_ |ssh-keygen -l -f -}
```

Answer (score 0):

If and when reading from `/dev/stdin` it's an issue you may want to use *process redirection* without temporary files:

```
while read -r l; do
  [[ -n "$l" && ${l###} = "$l" ]] && ssh-keygen -l -f <(echo "$l");
done < .ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a version of [ℝaphink's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/413231/how-to-get-all-fingerprints-for-ssh-authorized-keys2-file/413247#413247) that will work on all sh-compatible shells.

```sh
fingerprints() {
    _fingerprints_file="${1:-$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys}"
    while read -r l; do
        [ -n "$l" ] && [ "${l###}" = "$l" ] && printf '%s\n' "$l" | ssh-keygen -l -f /dev/stdin
    done < "${_fingerprints_file}"
    unset _fingerprints_file
}
```

Comment: `/dev/stdin` is a Bashism too; it is not guaranteed to work in non-Bash shells. Some OS platforms provide it, but not all.